# printing values to file and to terminal

Tags: perl, parsing, printing

Super nooby here.
Trying to get `$cssurl` to print to file vs. terminal but only getting one value printed in the file vs. terminal where everything prints.  How do I need to modify the code below to get what I need?

Here's the code:

```
use lib '/Users/lialin/perl5/lib/perl5';
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use File::Slurp 'slurp';    # makes it easy to read files.
use Mojo;
use Mojo::UserAgent;
use URI;

my $calls_dir = "Ask/";
opendir( my $search_dir, $calls_dir ) or die "$!\n";
my @html_files = grep /\.html$/i, readdir $search_dir;
closedir $search_dir;
#print "Got ", scalar @files, " files\n";

foreach my $html_files (@html_files) {
    my %seen         = ();
    my $current_file = $calls_dir . $html_files;
    open my $FILE, '<', $current_file or die "$html_files: $!\n";

    my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( scalar slurp $calls_dir . $html_files );
    print $calls_dir . $html_files;

    for my $csshref ( $dom->find('a[href]')->attr('href')->each ) {
        my $cssurl = URI->new($csshref)->abs( $calls_dir . $html_files );

        open my $fh, '>', "Ask/${html_files}.result.txt" or die $!;
        $fh->print("$html_files\n");
        $fh->print("$cssurl\n");
        #$fh->print("\t"."$_\n");
        print "$cssurl\n";
        #print $file."\t"."$_\n";
    }
}
```

In the terminal I get this:

```
http://www.scigene.com/
about 500 of other urls in here that stack overflow won't let me post
http://feedback.ask.com
```

Written to the file I get this:

```
Agilent_Technologies_ask.html
http://feedback.ask.com
```

So I just get the last line.

Comment: An example of what you need would be useful.

Comment: If I run the above script in terminal I get this:http://www.scigene.com/
http://www.scigene.com/contact.php
http://www.scigene.com/cms.php?mlink=Ordering&mlinkid=31&cmsid=84
http://www.scigene.com/cms.php?mlink=Corporate&mlinkid=29&cmsid=73
http://www.scigene.com/cms.php?mlinkid=43&mlink=Support&cmsid=81
http://www.scigene.com/cms.php?mlinkid=29&mlink=Corporate&cmsid=72
-in the file I just get this-Agilent_Technologies_ask.html
http://feedback.ask.com

Comment: You are opening your file in write mode (`>`) inside your loop, which will truncate the file on each iteration. You should open the file before your loop. See [`perldoc -f open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) for details.

Comment: You can always use shell redirection: `perl script.pl > output.txt`

Comment: (Incidentally, [File::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp) also has [read_dir](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp#read_dir).)

Comment: Or you could open the file in append mode.  Also make sure to close any open filehandles

Comment: @johnsmith Re-opening the file for every additional line of output wouldn't be very efficient. Also, since the OP is using lexical filehandles, they will be closed automatically as soon as the corresponding variables go out of scope (i.e. at the end of the enclosing block), so it's not strictly necessary to `close` them explicitly. Some people feel dirty if they don't close all their filehandles, though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arises because you're reopening the same file multiple times and overwriting the contents each time you open it. If you think about it logically, you want to create one output file per input file that you parse, so it would be best to create the output file when you open the input file:

```
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( scalar slurp $calls_dir . $html_files );
open my $fh, '>', "Ask/${html_files}.result.txt" or die $!;
```

If there is any material that only needs to be printed once (a file header, etc.), this needs to be done before you start looping through the URLs.

Your `for` loop would look like this now:

```
foreach my $html_files (@html_files) {

    my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( scalar slurp $calls_dir . $html_files );
    print $calls_dir . $html_files;

    open my $fh, '>', "Ask/${html_files}.result.txt" or die $!;
    $fh->print("$html_files\n");

    for my $csshref ( $dom->find('a[href]')->attr('href')->each ) {
        my $cssurl = URI->new($csshref)->abs( $calls_dir . $html_files );

        $fh->print("$cssurl\n");
        print "$cssurl\n";
    }
}
```